# How to find the highest node per k-group on a dendrogram in R?

Tags: r, dendrogram, dendextend

I am using `dendextend` to work with dendrograms in R. I want to only draw nodes that sit at the highest height within each cluster, which is determined by a tree cut @ *k* value. I wonder, if there is a convenient way to do that?

Reproducible example below.

```
###### sample tree ######

library(dendextend)
library(dplyr)

dend15 <- c(1:5) %>%
   dist %>%
   hclust(method = "average") %>%
   as.dendrogram()


###### plotting with clusters based on k #######

## it is not very intuitive from available tutorials,
## but you can control which nodes are (not) displayed by
## feeding vector with NAs to set() function

node_xy <- get_nodes_xy(dend15) ## all node xy coordinates
## setting node shapes
v <- rep(NA, nrow(node_xy)) ## vector of length of number of nodes
v[c(2,5)] <- 19 ## shape 19 to nodes 2 and 5 (i know because I looked at `node_xy`)

dend15 <- dend15 %>% set("nodes_pch",v) ## set nodes shapes

dend15 %>% plot(main="sample tree with highest nodes in k")
dend15 %>% rect.dendrogram(k=2) ## draw rectangles around clusters at cut
```

[image: a dendrogram cut to k=2]

I want to determine the nodes that I need to draw for any dendrogram and any *k*. More generally, I guess, I am asking about a way to utilize information from `cutree()`and `rect.dendrogram()` with `dendextend` data for controlling nodes.

**UPD**

`heights_per_k.dendrogram()` function returns tree heights at different *k* cuts, so nodes can be selected by these heights, e.g. `height @ k > node_h > height @ k+1`. However, this will not include cases when a single leaf forms a cluster (at k=3 on the example above).